# Strengthen attracting well

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I have the following equation $\dot{x}=-x^3+bx$. I know the equation has three equilibrium points for  $b>0$: $0$ (unstable) and $\pm\sqrt b$ (stable).  .

My question is can I make the strength of the attractor at one of the stable points (let's choose $\sqrt b$) while maintaining the same attractor strength at the other stable point ($-\sqrt b$)?

If I were to multiply the RHS by a constant $\alpha>1$ such that $\dot{x}=\alpha(-x^3+bx)$, I could increase the slope at each fixed point. However, I cannot determine how to increase the slope only at a single fixed point, if it is possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might mean the stable points are at $0$, $\pm \sqrt b$; what do you think?

Comment: @ Robert Lewis: Thanks for catching that typo.